# mysql export into single excell cell different records

Tags: php

Hello I am exporting data from mysql table to excel, I am using a popular code circulating over the internet for the excel export. The problem is that inside my SQL query I am going over a few selections from table which results should be put inside the same excel cell.

Basicaly in one excel cell for column name "titulo" and "status" there are variouse results from the table, right now it lists only one result and I would like to put all the results in one cell of excel devided with comma for example.

Here is the code with the SQL dump:

```
$sql = "SELECT users.*, cursos.titulo, subscriptions.status
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscriptions
ON users.userID = subscriptions.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN cursos
ON cursos.id = subscriptions.curso_id";



//Optional: print out title to top of Excel or Word file with Timestamp
//for when file was generated:
//set $Use_Titel = 1 to generate title, 0 not to use title
$Use_Title = 0;
//define date for title: EDIT this to create the time-format you need
$now_date = DATE('m-d-Y H:i');
//define title for .doc or .xls file: EDIT this if you want
$title = "Dump For Table $DB_TBLName from Database $DB_DBName on $now_date";
/*

Leave the connection info below as it is:
just edit the above.

(Editing of code past this point recommended only for advanced users.)
*/
//create MySQL connection
$Connect = @MYSQL_CONNECT($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
     or DIE("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR() . "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
//select database
$Db = @MYSQL_SELECT_DB($DB_DBName, $Connect)
     or DIE("Couldn't select database:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());
//execute query
$result = @MYSQL_QUERY($sql,$Connect)
     or DIE("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());

//if this parameter is included ($w=1), file returned will be in word format ('.doc')
//if parameter is not included, file returned will be in excel format ('.xls')
IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1))
{
     $file_type = "msword";
     $file_ending = "doc";
}ELSE {
     $file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
     $file_ending = "xls";
}
//header info for browser: determines file type ('.doc' or '.xls')
HEADER("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
HEADER("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MDT_DB_$now_date.$file_ending");
HEADER("Pragma: no-cache");
HEADER("Expires: 0");

/*    Start of Formatting for Word or Excel    */

IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1)) //check for $w again
{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR WORD DOCUMENTS ('.doc')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\n"; //new line character

     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
         //define field names
         $field_name = MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$j);
         //will show name of fields
         $schema_insert .= "$field_name:\t";
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j])) {
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                 }
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "") {
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                 }
             ELSE {
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
                 }
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         //end of each mysql row
         //creates line to separate data from each MySQL table row
         PRINT "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
     }
}ELSE{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR EXCEL DOCUMENTS ('.xls')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

     //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
     FOR ($i = 0; $i < MYSQL_NUM_FIELDS($result); $i++)
     {
         ECHO MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$i) . "\t";
     }
     PRINT("\n");
     //end of printing column names

     //start while loop to get data
     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j]))
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "")
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
             ELSE
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         //following fix suggested by Josue (thanks, Josue!)
         //this corrects output in excel when table fields contain \n or \r
         //these two characters are now replaced with a space
         $schema_insert = PREG_REPLACE("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         PRINT "\n";
     }
     }

?>
```

So right now in php what this is doing is exporting all the data from table users depending how many times user_id is inside the subscription table. I would like the information from the subscription table to be put inside a single excel cell for every user

[image: cursos database]

[image]

What I think right now is that maybe the SQL Query is not the correct one because right now it creates new arrays for every match from the subscription table and it list all the infromation from users just with diferent fields titulo and status

Comment: You probably want [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Out of interest, why do you put all the PHP code in capitals? It's rather odd to see... PL/SQL background? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple local machine code for generating xls or csv file, modify as per your requirement

```
SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE 'c:/folder/excel.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```